# Integer formatting, padding to a given length

Tags: c#, string, integer, format

I need to pad the output of an integer to a given length.

For example, with a length of 4 digits, the output of the integer 4 is "0004" instead of "4". How can I do this in C# 2.0?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the string.Format command.

```
output = String.Format("{0:0000}", intVariable);
```

More details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx

Answer (score 2):

i think it was: 
intVal.ToString( "####" );

but there is some [useful documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wch342y.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

**In modern .NET 5.0+** (2021 update)

```
int myint = 100;
string zeroPadded = $"{myint:d8}";      // "00000100"
string leftPadded = $"{myint,8}";       // "     100"
string rightPadded = $"{myint,-8}";     // "100     "
```